# Confused on the logic of multiple joins on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

I'm having a little problem with extracting and counting data from my database due to the way the database is setup.

Each case has multiple customers and suppliers with one main supplyer.

The main problems i need to over come are as follows:

1. To be able to first count the full amount of customers between a period of months driven by when the suppler jonied the company.
2. Count how many customers have had an "initial contact" as sometimes there will be no initial contact in the database.

I have tried to do this by using multiple joins in a single query but this doesn't seem to return complete data.

I'm so confused with using multiple joins, i understand that they can be executed in any order but i'm unsure what the second join is running on and also is i can legally join unrelated table in the same query or if i need to do a seperate query to do this.

Please find below a recreation of one of my many queries below with a very simplfied picture :

```
SELECT Count(cc.customercase)
FROM   customer cc
       LEFT JOIN customer
              ON cc.custid = c.custid
       LEFT JOIN maincase m
              ON m.id = cc.caseid
       LEFT JOIN custcontactlog cl
              ON cl.caseid = cc.custcaseid
       LEFT JOIN supcase sc
              ON sc.caseid = m.id
WHERE  cl.contactlogtype = 'Initial Contact'
       AND sc.primarysupplyer = 1
       AND Calctargetdate(sc.joindate) > cl.postdate
       AND cl.postdate > sc.joindate
       AND c.gender = 'M'
       AND sc.joindate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/2012', 103) AND
                               CONVERT(DATETIME, '31/03/2012', 103)
```

http://i50.tinypic.com/2qk3pqa.png

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that as you trying to achieve two things so you should have two separate queries to achieve it.

Comment: Hi, 
I should make clear that the query shown should reflect part 2, i am currently writing seperate queries per objective.
Thanks